# read message from mule in java class

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

How to read `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` in java class.

my configuration is:

```
<flow name="file-processFlow3" doc:name="file-processFlow3">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" queue="OrchestratorQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" responseTimeout="0" >
            <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10000"/>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <component doc:name="Java"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

[image]

I don't know how can I read the input message in my java class( `<component doc:name="Java"/>`). assume any class, I'm not yet implemented I don't know how to implement.
Please any one help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a single method in your class, it will be invoked automatically.

flow:

```
<set-payload value="world" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<component doc:name="Java" class="my.test.Klass"/>
```

Java class:

```
package my.test;

public class Klass {

    public String methhod (String s) {
        return "hello "+s;
    }
}
```

If you need something more complex you can define entry points, factories, etc.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Java+Components

UPDATE:

For classes with multiple methods, you need to define an entry point resolver. The simplest approach is to use method name:

```
<component doc:name="Java" class="my.test.Klass">
    <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="methhod" />
    </method-entry-point-resolver>
</component>
```

Comment: Updated my answer for the multiple methods case.